# FireFox text-overflow ellipsis hack removes all other styling

Tags: html, css, firefox, ellipsis

I'm trying to implement `text-overflow: ellipsis;` support in the FireFox version of my web site.  I've found the XUL hack on the web and have applied it to the stylesheet, but I find that applying the hack removes all other styling from the element.  In other words, I can either have the ellipsis, or I can have the background image, gradients, line-height, etc.

How can I get the ellipsis hack to work alongside my other styles?

Comment: What's the hack — link? It will presumably be adding extra elements, which might change how the other CSS rules are interpreted.

Comment: This is the hack I'm using: http://www.rikkertkoppes.com/thoughts/2008/6/

Answer (score 0):

Put an extra div around the element, and give that one all the background and fonts, then set the text-overflow on the child.

Comment: Tried this a few days ago and ran into a problem where the div (or span) would wrap to the next line and wouldn't be located to the right of the icon like it was supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
word-wrap: normal;
max-width: 130px;
vertical-align: bottom;
```

This works in IE 7, IE 8, IE 9, IE 10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari